# Converting data file to flatfile?

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-conversion

I'm looking to convert a data file to a flat file format, with multiple hierarchical dimensions. I have included an example, but ideally, I will have an unknown number of columns that I wish to transform, while the hierarchical dimensions will be fixed.

[image: 1]

Comment: There is not a lot of explanation in this question.... How do you get from a table with 4 columns and 16 rows to ta table with two time that number of rows ?

Comment: Something like this?  SELECT country, city, 'Snowfall' AS Metric, Snowfall as Value FROM original_data UNION SELECT country, city, 'Temp' AS metric, Temp as value from original_data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have unknown or variable columns, you can dynamically UNPIVOT your data without using Dynamic SQL.  Note that we only need to exclude the two key columns ... `Where [key] not in ('Country','City')`

**Example**

```
Select Country
      ,City
      ,Metric = B.[key]
      ,Value  = B.Value 
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( Select * 
                From  OpenJson( (Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper  )  ) 
                Where [key] not in ('Country','City')
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
Country City    Metric      Value
US      NY      Snowfall    13
US      NY      Temp        94
US      NY      Snowfall    5
US      NY      Temp        84
UK      London  Snowfall    6
UK      London  Temp        85
```

Comment: This looks dangerously close to magic to me.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You're too funny.  :)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti . . . It may take me a long time to really remember this, so I don't think I'm going to get dynamic pivot questions correct for a while.

Comment: how do you view all contents in a dynamic tabl? getting an error when running a basic select * from @YourTable

Comment: @JDR The (at)YourTable is just a demonstrative table variable.  Rather than (at)YourTable use any table desired.   Replace (at)YourTable with an actual table, view or subquery.

Answer (score 1):

you need to `unpivot` your data:

```
SELECT unpvt.country
     , unpvt.city
     , unpvt.metrics
     , unpvt.Valuess 
FROM 
( SELECT * FROM tablename ) p
UNPIVOT ( Valuess FOR metrics IN ( snowfall , temp) ) unpvt
```

Comment: Thanks! Anyway to do this where we dont have to list the columns? What if there are 100+ columns that I want to unpivot?

Comment: right - but no way to have this be dynamic so that it would automate?

Comment: then you need to build it by `dynamic query`

Comment: or go with John solution